# Selecting records having special char record

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, select-by-expression

I am trying to select all records which have special char (I'm not mention any specific special char)

Like below:

```sql
ADDRESS_N LIKE  '%Ö%' or
ADDRESS_N LIKE  '%Ü%' or
ADDRESS_N LIKE  '%ß%' or
ADDRESS_N LIKE  '%ä%' or
ADDRESS_N LIKE  '%ö%' or
ADDRESS_N LIKE  '%ü%'
```

How can I implement it in ArcMap?

Comment: How many records in total do you have?

Comment: That's a hideously inefficient query, but it will work just like that. Haven't you tried?

Comment: over all records 40k in that special char records nearly 10 to 40% percent  @BERA

Comment: I don't know about rest of the special chars so rest of the chars are not selecting from above query @Vince

Comment: Depending on the number of records, I'd just use a DA SearchCursor to suck the rows into RAM, and look for UTF-16 values outside of 32-126, then either append the offending rows or remove the innocent ones in blocks of 50 with an IN operator.

Comment: i didn't get what u say exactly @Vince

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about this, but try it in the python console of ArcMap:

```
import arcpy, string

feature_class = r'C:\folder\database\adresses' #Change to match your data source
fieldname = r'ADDRESS_N'

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=feature_class, out_layer='templayer') #Create a layer which you can select from

normal_letters = {ord(i) for i in string.ascii_lowercase}.union({ord(i) for i in string.ascii_uppercase}) #List all "normal" letter integers representing the Unicode code point

to_select = [] #A list to store object ids of the rows to select
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('templayer', ['OID@', fieldname]) as cursor: #For each table row, search for special chars
    for row in cursor:
        if not all(ord(char) in normal_letters for char in row[1]):
            to_select.append(row[0]) #if found, add oid to oid list
            
sql = """{0} IN{1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource='templayer', field=arcpy.Describe(feature_class).OIDFieldName, tuple(to_select)))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view='templayer', where_clause=sql)
```